# Split delimited string in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, regex, hana

I am using HANA 1.0 SPS12. Is there a way to split delimited string in SAP HANA.

I have Pipe delimited string as -

```
v_input = '1111|2222|3333|4444'
```

I need output base on position of delimited part -

```
select seperate_string(v_input,pos) from dummy;
```

for e.g.

```
select seperate_string('1111|2222|3333|4444',1 ) from dummy; --1111
select seperate_string('1111|2222|3333|4444',2 ) from dummy; --2222
select seperate_string('1111|2222|3333|4444',3 ) from dummy; --3333
```

Is it possible to do this with **SUBSTR_REGEXP**?

I tried below coded but it did not work -

```
select SUBSTR_REGEXPR('[^\|]+' IN '1111|2222|3333|4444' GROUP 1 ) from dummy;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can try the following SUBSTRING_REGEXPR()

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('[^|]+' IN '1111|2222|3333|44|555' FROM 1 OCCURRENCE 4) from dummy;
--44

SELECT SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('[^|]+' IN '1111|2222|3333|44|555' FROM 1 OCCURRENCE 2) from dummy;
--2222
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible with `SUBSTR_REGEXPR()`.

```
select SUBSTR_REGEXPR('(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)' IN  '1111|2222|3333|4444' GROUP 1 ) from dummy;  
-- 1111
select SUBSTR_REGEXPR('(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)' IN  '1111|2222|3333|4444' GROUP 2 ) from dummy;  
-- 2222
select SUBSTR_REGEXPR('(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)' IN  '1111|2222|3333|4444' GROUP 3 ) from dummy;  
-- 3333
select SUBSTR_REGEXPR('(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)\|(.+)' IN  '1111|2222|3333|4444' GROUP 4 ) from dummy;  
-- 4444
```

The regex builds four match-groups over the characters before a `|` and at the end of the string. The `GROUP x` parameter in the `SUBSTR_REGEXPR()` function specifies, which match-group should be returned.

Comment: thanks @Lars...but this will work for only four groups. Can I specify pattern for varying number of groups

Comment: Nope, that’s not possible and not what you asked initially.

Comment: Writing your own function for that could be one. That aside, how about you start closing some of your questions as you received answers?

Comment: One more thing as per SAP documentation of SUBSTR_REGEXP, it says SAP HANA supports Perl Compatible Regular Expression. So it should support patterns which are supported in Oracle etc. I get results while using  REGEXP_SUBSTR('A|B','[^\|]+',2) in Oracle. Why doesnt it support same pattern in SAP HANA.